# linux/ unix command for checking specific logs

Tags: linux, unix

how can I extract a log based on specific time frame? Let's say issue started between 4pm to 5pm, how can I get that specific log between those times? I can use `less` or `cat` or `grep` but it would not give me the details of the error, sample command:

```
grep "2013-08-26 16:00:00" sample.log
```

what is the more precise Linux/ Unix command that can do the trick?

Comment: What do entries in this log file look like?

Comment: there isn't one. you'd have to use a regex in grep to handle the time frame you want. as well, your grep sample above is incorrect. you'll be looking for the term `2013-08-26` in the files '16:00:00' and 'sample.log'. If your search term contains spaces the whole term must be enclosed in quotes, or the spaces escaped.

Comment: You can concatenate greps: `grep "2013-08-26 16:00:00" sample.log | grep ERROR`

Comment: @Marc B edited now...i missed that...

Comment: @alfasin yeah i can definitely do that thanks for the advise but the thing is it would only show the line which has an `ERROR` what i want is to get the details of the error already on specific time frame.

Comment: @user2579439 if you know the line number - you can easily navigate there using `vim` or `emacs`

Answer (score 2):

For viewing ERROR log messages between **16:00:00** and **17:00:00** use:

```
grep -nP '2013-08-15 16:.+ERROR' sample.log | less
```

If you have multiline messages in log you can use `-A n` and `-B n` params to add for each output string n lines after or before:

3 lines before and after each line:

```
grep -A 3 -B 3 -nP '2013-08-15 16:.+ERROR' sample.log | less
```

Shorthand for the same:

```
grep -3 -nP '2013-08-15 16:.+ERROR' sample.log | less
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know that  issue happened between 4 and 5 pm, you can use this:

```
grep "2013-08-26 16:" sample.log | less
```

If you need some lines around that issue, add option -N to grep (context of N lines), something like that:

```
grep -3 "2013-08-26 16:" sample.log | less
```

If you know that your event contained some specific word, you can filter it more using one more grep:

```
grep -3 "2013-08-26 16:" sample.log | grep somethingelse
```